# how do i print out the age multiplied by 3

Tags: java

I want the age to be multiplied by 3 here is my code asking for the user to enter name and age...............................................

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Lab1Part4 {

 public static void main (String [] args) {

Scanner user_input = 
    int tripleAge;
    String printMyName;
    String firstName;
    String secondName;

    System.out.println("Please enter your first name ? ");
    firstName = user_input.next ();

    System.out.println("Please enter your second name? ");
    secondName = user_input.next ();

    printMyName = firstName + " " + secondName;

    System.out.println( printMyName);

    System.out.println("Enter your age ? ");
    tripleAge = user_input.nextInt ();







}// end class
```

}// end main

Comment: What don't you understand how to do? Print a value? Multiply a number by 3?

Comment: And what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do something like:

```
tripleAge = user_input.nextInt () * 3;
System.out.println(tripleAge);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `*` operator to multiply.

```
tripleAge = (user_input.nextInt () * 3);
System.out.println(tripleAge);
```